# Making IKImageView aware of my custom NSImageRep

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, ikimageview, nsimagerep

In my application, I’ve written a custom `NSImageRep` to handle a proprietary image format. The application’s primary view is an `IKImageView`, which I intend to load the images I’ve made the custom `NSImageRep` for into for viewing and manipulation.

If I create a `CGImageRef` of these images and then pass the reference over to the image view it works fine, but this is not ideal. If possible, I’d like to make use of `IKImageView`’s `setImageWithURL:` method, as this is mentioned as being the preferred method by the docs, plus it’s just cleaner. Unfortunately the view seems entirely ignorant of my `NSImageRep` and simply fails to load the image.

Is there anything that can be done to make the image view understand custom representations?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call NSImageRep's registerImageRepClass: sometime early in your app's startup.

I'm fairly sure you also need to implement imageUnfilteredTypes in your sub-class

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSImageRep/registerImageRepClass: